# My puppy when playing with my older dog has bitten and clamped on

Tags: dogs, psychology

I have an 11yr old westie, and a 3 month old Lakeland puppy. More than once now the puppy has clamped onto my Westies side, and wont let go. Its very concerning behaviour and means they have to be watched all the time. How do I effectively discourage and stop this behaviour ?